# Can i create a login page using mysql without PHP

Tags: sql, authentication

Can i create a login page using mysql without PHP? thanks

Comment: There are other front-ends other than PHP. The question is too broad without more context. Do you mean strictly MySQL-only, or what?

Comment: We are going to make a web app with a login. PHP is not yet taught to us so I thought if is it possible for a login with database using MYSQL only? Because when I search for login with database, all examples have PHP. Thank you